# Compare a list with a multi list in R

Tags: r, list

I have a multi list `q` like this

```
[[1]]
[1]   1   2   3   4   5   6  10  12  15  20  32  49  57  74 100

[[2]]
[1]  1  2  3 13 27

[[3]]
[1]  4 21 73

[[4]]
[1]  1  2  3  4 11 25 28 42

[[5]]
[1]  1  2  3  4 26

[[6]]
[1]  1  2  3 11
```

and I have another list `d`

```
[1]  5 11 14 18 38 61
```

Now how do I compare `d` with all the list elements in `q`?
I need something like this `length(intersect(q,d))` should return list of `length(q)`. The number of terms between `d` and each list in `q`.
As the length of `q` is around a million. What is the efficient way of implementing?
Edit: the desired output should be like :

```
1 0 0 1 0 1
```

As there is only one common item between `d` and `q[[1]]`, `q[[4]]`, `q[[6]]` the output is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `vapply`

```
vapply(q, function(x) length(intersect(x, d)), 1L)
# [1] 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Not sure, but it might be faster to do

```
vapply(q, function(x) sum(x %in% d), 1L)
# [1] 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

... And it turns out that it is considerably faster to use `sum(x %in% d)` :

```
qq <- rep(q, 1e4)
length(qq)
# [1] 60000

f <- function() vapply(qq, function(x) length(intersect(x, d)), 1L)
g <- function() vapply(qq, function(x) sum(x %in% d), 1L)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f(), g(), times = 10, unit = "relative")
# Unit: relative
#  expr    min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   f() 8.4694 8.466754 8.311812 8.557292 8.447665 7.095008    10   b
#   g() 1.0000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a 


identical(f(), g())
# [1] TRUE
```

Where the original `q` list is

```
q <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20, 32, 49, 57, 74, 100), 
          c(1, 2, 3, 13, 27), c(4, 21, 73), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 25, 28, 42),  
          c(1, 2, 3, 4, 26), c(1, 2, 3, 11))
```